# Recall Disowned Process Mac

Tags: bash, unix, process

I'm doing some neural network training and my process needed to run for about 20 hours. Following some bad advice elsewhere I `disowned` my process to keep it running when I put my macbook air to sleep.

Now I realize I can't get the process, which is still running, back. However, it is really important I get my process back as this was an important training run.

I'm hoping some Unix genius knows some really hacky way of getting back this particular process in this particular instance. I know this is not usually possible, but there must be a way to do it, right?

Please don't tell me to use tmux. That would be nice if I could do so retroactively. I need a solution to my problem now, not in the future ( I ran my process late at night forgetting I was not in tmux).

Answer (score 1):

this tool may help you : [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr).
You just have to compile it then use this like this :

```
./reptyr PID
```

then it will reattach it to the current tty. Hope this help.

Comment: I'm on a mac. Do you think it will compile

Comment: Since it is written in C I think so. Please let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: I get an error when I `make` it: `/usr/local/bin/gcc-6 -Wall -Werror -D_GNU_SOURCE -g    -c -o reptyr.o reptyr.c
In file included from reptyr.c:37:0:
platform/platform.h:60:25: error: field 'addr' has incomplete type
         struct sockaddr addr;
                         ^~~~
platform/platform.h:61:28: error: field 'addr_un' has incomplete type
         struct sockaddr_un addr_un;
                            ^~~~~~~
make: *** [reptyr.o] Error 1`

Comment: Do you know if you have platform.h header installed on your system ?